# APACHE POI set formula by column name format

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Have small problem when I want to set formula to cell by column name format. Let me show example:

In excel file I can do something like this =[Name]

[image]

So value from colmn B is copied to column A

But when I try to do something like this in Apache POI

```
  cell.setCellFormula("[Name]");
```

I get exception:

> Parse error near char 0 '[' in specified formula '[Name]'. Expected number, string, defined name, or data table"

How can I handle such situation?

Comment: If you set a formula like that in Excel, save the file, and read it back with Apache POI, what did Excel actually write in the file for the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula `=[Name]` is a [structured reference to an Excel table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e). But it is a very short unqualified form. The fully qualified form would be `=tableName[[#This Row],[Name]]`, And that fully qualified form also will be stored and so must be set using `apache poi`.

Let's have a complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;

class CreateExcelTableUsingStructuredReferences {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx") ) {

   //data
   String[] tableHeadings = new String[]{"Id", "Name", "Description"};
   String[] tableContent = new String[]{null, "Name1", "Description1"};
   //variables
   String tableName = "Table1";
   int firstRow = 0; //start table in row 1
   int firstCol = 0; //start table in column A
   int rows = 2; //we have to populate headings row and 1 data row
   int cols = 3; //three columns in each row
   
   //prepairing the sheet
   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   
   //set sheet content  
   for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) { 
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(firstRow+r);
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) { 
     XSSFCell localXSSFCell = row.createCell(firstCol+c);
     if (r == 0) {
      localXSSFCell.setCellValue(tableHeadings[c]);
     } else {
      localXSSFCell.setCellValue(tableContent[c]);
     }
    }
   }
   
   //create the table
   CellReference topLeft = new CellReference(sheet.getRow(firstRow).getCell(firstCol));
   CellReference bottomRight = new CellReference(sheet.getRow(firstRow+rows-1).getCell(firstCol+cols-1));
   AreaReference tableArea = workbook.getCreationHelper().createAreaReference(topLeft, bottomRight);
   XSSFTable dataTable = sheet.createTable(tableArea);
   dataTable.setName(tableName);
   dataTable.setDisplayName(tableName);
   
   //set table column formula
   dataTable.getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().get(0).addNewCalculatedColumnFormula().setStringValue(
      tableName + "[[#This Row],[Name]]");

   //set the formula in sheet
   XSSFCell formulaCell = sheet.getRow(firstRow+1).getCell(firstCol);
   formulaCell.setCellFormula(tableName + "[[#This Row],[Name]]");
   //following is not necessary up to apache poi 5.1.0, but later versions of apache poi uses formula parser which damages structured table formulas
   formulaCell.getCTCell().getF().setStringValue(tableName + "[[#This Row],[Name]]");
   
   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

This works using `apache poi 4` or later.

Note, the additional `formulaCell.getCTCell().getF().setStringValue(tableName + "[[#This Row],[Name]]");` is only needed using `apache poi` versions after `5.1.0`. Later versions of `apache poi` uses a formula parser which damages the structured table formula and so it must be reset using this code line.

Comment: If there's no unit test in the Apache POI test suite showing the break in 5.1+ then no-one will know there's anything to fix... :(

Comment: @Gagravarr: I cannot help with the Unit test. This testing method is useless in my opinion. Don't assume a software is working properly just because it passes a Unit test. A software needs to be tested by examples. But there is https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66039 now showing that issue.

Comment: Come join us on Apache Tika then - we run Tika against a few TBs of files, look at a summary of the exceptions + types + resources etc, then try to decide if on the whole it looks better or worse.... https://lists.apache.org/thread/pk00xjpvojz45bs91nxo7olro8pdzjlq

Comment: the reformatting of the formula can be disabled using workbook.setCellFormulaValidation(false) - which might be a useful workaround until bug-66039 is fixed

Comment: @PJ Fanning: Why is `setCellFormulaValidation(false)` not the default? And why it is not documented anywhere where `XSSFCell.setCellFormula` is documented? And why only re-validation of given formulas in `XSSF`? What about `HSSF`?

Comment: I didn't add the option and only learned about it today - I sort of agree that it should have defaulted to false and been documented better - but it's hard to change that now - can definitely start improving the docs though